# With gsutil tool, is possible to list files where the filename matches a regex?

Tags: gsutil

I want to list files that do not start with a certain prefix. I can list them fine, like this:

```
gsutil ls gs://my_bucket/my_prefix*
```

How do I do the inverse of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do what you're talking about is to list the bucket and filter the results on your local machine, e.g.,

gsutil ls gs://mybucket/** | grep -v gs://my_bucket/my_prefix